# Does inheritance break encapsulation in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

I read (Scott Myers) that inheritance breaks encapsulation. When data/internal methods are private (not protected), is encapsulation broken?

e.g.

```
class Vehicle
{
  int color;

public:
  void set_color();
  int get_color();
}


class Car: public Vehicle
{
public:
  void change_tires();
}
```

I can change the internals of Vehicle without breaking Car ever knowing, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phrases like "inheritance breaks encapsulation" are often taken out of context.

What the phrase refers to is the fact that the virtual interface being inherited is now not encapsulated. In effect, inheritance means that certain things that were hidden are now exposed. Things like `protected` members and `virtual` `private` members are all open for play by derived classes.

Non-`virtual` `private` members are still hidden.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on **virtual private members** *are all open for play by derived classes*?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont know what Scott Myers said, but anyway, by doing the way you specified, a car method can only access the Vehicle public methods and properties exactly the same way that you would be able if you created a Vehicle object (there are no protected methods and properties), so there are no encapsulation breaking over here, only if the base class is not correctly encapsulated. You will only be able to change the color of the Car by using set_color(...) method, since int color is private (class properties and functions are private if not specified).